# Freemarker call static java method from java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, freemarker

i have a question. I would like to call a static java method `Integer.toHexString()` in a freemaker template.
In my code i implemented following lines:

```
....
cfg.setSharedVariable("Integer",BeansWrapper.getDefaultInstance().
                                getStaticModels().
                                get("java.lang.Integer");
....
);
```

My template looks like this

```
<#list Items.iterator() as var>
  <#assign hex = Integer.toHexString(var) />
  ${hex}
</#list>
```

But if i execute the code i get following error:

```
freemarker.core._TemplateModelException: An error has occurred when reading existing sub-variable "Integer"; see cause exception! The type of the containing value was: extended_hash+string (org.json.JSONObject wrapped into f.e.b.StringModel)

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: #assign hex = Integer.toHexString(var...  [in template "decToHex.ftl"...]
```

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error message, your data-model (aka. template context) is a `org.json.JSONObject`. FreeMarker doesn't know that API, but it discovers that `JSONObject` has a `get(String)` method, and tries to use that. Unfortunately, that `get` method doesn't behave as a `Map`-style `get(key)`. FreeMarker first calls `JSONObject.get("Integer")` to see if the variable is in the data-model. If it isn't, it expects a `null` to be returned, and then will try to get it from higher scopes (like from the shared variables). But `JSONObject.get(String)` throws `JSONException` instead of returning `null`, which is what you see in the error log (if you look at the whole stack trace, `JSONException` should be there as the cause exception).

To solve this, you need teach FreeMarker how to deal with `JSONObject`-s:

1. Create a class, let's call it `JSONObjectAdapter`, which implements `TemplateHashModelEx2` (or, the much simpler `TemplateHashModel` can be enough for basic use-cases). Inside that, when implementing `TemplateHashModel.get(String)`, you must call `JSONObject.has(key)` to check if the key exists, and if not, return `null`, otherwise continue with calling `JSONObject.get(key)`.
2. Create a class, let's call it `DefaultObjectWrapperWithJSONSupport`, that extends `DefaultObjectWrapper`. Your class should wrap `JSONObject`-s with `JSONObjectAdapter`.
3. Where you already configure FreeMarker (NOT before each template processing), specify the `objectWrapper` to be a `DefaultObjectWrapperWithJSONSupport`.

There's a few non-obvious things with doing above properly, so I strongly recommend starting out from this example:
https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_datamodel_objectWrapper.html#pgui_datamodel_customObjectWrappingExample

Above linked example does the above 3 steps, but to support the `Tupple` class, instead of `JSONObject`. That's a `TemplateSequenceModel`, instead of `TemplateHashModel`, but otherwise what has to be done is very similar.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. It's the first time i use freemarker.